# Better "bro ol"

Tags: user-commands

Inspired by a [nice solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21937545/use-search-in-browse-oldfiles-list) on a Stack Overflow, the following was put in my `vimrc`:

```
command! Bro :vnew +setl\ buftype=nofile | 0put =v:oldfiles 
  \| nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :e <C-r>=getline('.')<CR><CR>
```

There are two problems with it I'd like to fix:

1. I want to view the list from the top (most recent) rather than the bottom, as is currently the case. I've tried adding `1G` to the script, but to no avail.
2. I would rather the list be open in the current window, so I don't have to come back to close it later. Using `enew` instead of `vnew` produces an E488 error, and `e` puts the list of files in current file.

Thanks.

**Update.** Since the purpose of this exercise is to make the file list searchable, it's probably a good idea to append `:noh<CR>` to the `nnoremap` so that once you've searched, found your file, and opened it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, search terms are not highlighted in the file.

Comment: Just a note, `1G` doesn't work here because you are basically in command-line mode (or ex-mode for purists) and `1G` is a normal mode command.

Comment: FWIW, my answer to the linked question is *a lot* cleaner than that hack.

Comment: @Tumbler41 How dumb of me! I thought `1G` was a command-line mode, too. Somehow, although I never did `:1G`, I thought it would work until I tried just now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work:

```
command! Bro :enew | setl buftype=nofile |  0put =v:oldfiles
  \| nnoremap <buffer> <CR> gf | 1
```

[`:enew`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aenew) doesn't support [`+cmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%5B%2Bcmd%5D), unlike `:vnew`, so just split the `:setl` out to a new, chained, command.

I changed the mapping to use [`gf`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#gf), which IMHO, is more native. The last command, `1`, should move the cursor to the first line. Unlike the `:e … getline()` version, `gf` will fail if the file doesn't exist - the help in fact suggests using that if you always want to edit a new file if it doesn't exit and suggests a simpler variant:

```
To make gf always work like that: 
        :map gf :e <cfile><CR>
```

So you could also do `nnoremap <buffer> <CR> :e <cfile><CR>`. But I suppose this isn't really a problem - files in the history are more likely to exist than not. :)

Comment: Thank you! You're right that `gf` is more native, but it doesn't work when there's a space the path (e.g. Window's  `Program Files`).

Comment: @bongbang that's part of the beauty of `gf` - what it includes can be customized using `isfname` (`:set isfname^=\ `), you can optionally add suffixes to check with `suffixesadd`, and if a file can't be found, it uses `includeexpr` which can be used to modify the filename how you want to check again. Though I suppose Ingo's version is far simpler.